# How to put a large Text File in Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs

I am trying to process the Large Text file using spark, after installing the Spark cluster in Ec2 with 8 Gb of memory. How do I put my 100 GB of file in the hdfs to be able to process it using spark-scala script?

I am using following command

```
./hadoop fs -put /user/myuser/example.txt /src
```

but its throwing an Exception as follows

```
WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/myuser/example.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)

WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/myuser/example.txt" - Aborting...
put: java.io.IOException: File /user/myuser/example.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /user/myuser/example.txt
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/myuser/example.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)
```

Comment: Check the heath of your name nodes. https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/TroubleShooting#Error_message:_Could_not_get_block_locations._Aborting...

Comment: what is the capacity of file system? run hdfs dfsadmin -report to figure out

Comment: you probably do not have enough space or your default replication is set to a number higher than what your cluster is capable of handling. try running `hadoop fs -count -q /src` to check the namespace and diskspace limits and current usage.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It doesn't have enough space left. How do I increase that space using configuration, I tried mounting the disk on Ec2 instance. But not sure how to make Hdfs to read from that mounted disk ?